# Convert Python Series of strings into float with 18 decimals

Tags: python, floating-point, formatting, series

I have the following pandas Series:

```
my_series = ['150000000000000000000000', '45064744242514231410', '2618611848503168287542', '7673975728717793369']
```

Every number in the list has 18 decimal places (that's what dictates what number exactly it is, prior to seeing any formatting).

`my_series[0]`, therefore, is 150,000.000000000000000000 (one hundred and fifty thousand).

`my_series[1]`, therefore, is 45.064744242514231410 (fourty-five...).

And so on.

I basically want Python to recognize the strings and tunr them into the correct float for me to make calculations with thie Series later.
I don't need to print the correct formatted number, rather, have Pythoin recognize it's a 150,000 instead of a 1,500,000,000 and so on.

Example for `my_series[2]` of what the corrrect float would be:

**2,618.61**

My current code:

```
[float("{:.18f}".format(int(item) for item in my_series))]
```

Which yields me the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to generator.__format__
```

How do I format the strings in the Series according to my requirements above and get the correct float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string to float and then apply formatting.

```py
my_series = ['150000000000000000000000', '45064744242514231410',
             '2618611848503168287542', '7673975728717793369']
["{:,.2f}".format(float(item)/10**18) for item in my_series]
```

```
['150,000.00', '45.06', '2,618.61', '7.67']
```

Note that this may lose some precision when converting the string to float.
If this is a problem to you, then you may want to use either

- Separate the integer part and decimal part and combine them when printing
- Use Decimal class

Answer (score 1):

After a few iterations, I think I understand what OP was going for, so I changed my example. OP does not seem to be worried about loss of precision and was getting value errors (probably due to invalid fields coming in as part of the Series). I've modified my sample to be close to how it would happen in Pandas by adding some deliberately fake inputs.

```
my_series = [
    "not a number",
    "",
    "150000000000000000000000",
    "45064744242514231410",
    "2618611848503168287542",
    "7673975728717793369",
]


def convert_to_float(number):
    float_string = None
    my_float = None
    try:
        float_string = f"{int(number[:-18])}.{number[-18:]}"
        my_float = float(float_string)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        return None

    return my_float

numbers = list(map(convert_to_float, my_series))

for num in numbers:
    if num:
        print(f"{num :.18f}")
```

Comment: I get the following error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`. And also want to turn it into a float.

Comment: Odd, I'm guessing you are working out of a list that might have an empty string in which case you would need to handle that?  I would advise you do not convert to float to avoid losing precision. There are better types such as decimal if you need that kind of precision, but for formatting it is certainly not required.

Comment: Gotcha. Well, I basically wnat to have a correct float so that I can make calculations with this series. Right now all numbers are strings and I just want Python to recognize it as the correct string. Perhaps I phrased my question wrong.

Comment: I've modified the example a little to store the number as well and not lose precision

Comment: Still getting the same error. But in any case, your solution simply formats the string, whereas I'd need Python to recognize floats, so that I can make calculations. The only information I have is that all numbers have 18 cedimals. How do I make Python understand that and read the numbers as floats accordingly?

Comment: My code is just a sample. Within your app, you need to sanitize your inputs and look out for inputs that are an empty string (or otherwise invalid), which I'm guessing is where your error is coming from. If you look at my example, it no longer simply formats. It converts it to a type called Decimal which has higher precision than float. If you have them as floats there is a risk your numbers will come out different. If you are not worried about loss of precision , I can edit my example with floats.